# Qual a melhor maneira de criar métodos acessíveis a qualquer activity?

Tags: android, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Olá. Quando eu preciso criar um método para uma Activity eu simplesmente escrevo ele no código da minha Activity. Por exemplo:

```
package com.pcriot.maxsoft.testapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void MeuMetodo() {
        // Código aqui
    }
}
```

Mas agora, digamos que este método que eu criei precise ser chamado em todas as outras activities. Seria aconselhável criar uma classe para escrever os métodos que seriam utilizados pelas activities?

Uma classe como esta:

```
package com.pcriot.maxsoft.testapplication;

import android.content.Context;

public class Functions {
    private Context context = null;

    public Functions(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void MeuMetodo1() {
        // Código aqui
    }

    public void MeuMetodo2() {
        // Código aqui
    }

    public void MeuMetodo3() {
        // Código aqui
    }
}
```

Depois eu poderia chamar cada um deles assim:

```
package com.pcriot.maxsoft.testapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Functions Functions = new Functions(MainActivity.this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Functions.MeuMetodo1();
    }
}
```

Então? A maneira que estou fazendo está correta? Ou existe algum outro jeito e que tenha alguma vantagem que eu ainda não saiba.

Comment: Acho que estás a fazer bem, não estou a ver outra forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As possíveis formas de fazer (que me ocorrem) são:

**1) Criar uma SuperActivity que as outras Activities estendam e portanto herdem o método em questão:**

**Vantagem:** Se colocar o método em uma SuperActivity for uma decisão de design que faça sentido, o método já estará imediatamente disponível para você em suas outras activities, sem precisar instanciar uma classe que contenha o dito método;

**Desvantagem:** Você será obrigado a ter SuperActivity como superclasse de todas as Activities que precisarem desse método, o que torna o código mais *brittle* (engessado). Por isso essa maneira de fornecer o método só deve ser utilizada quando fizer sentido em seu design de classes.

**2) Tornar o método estático e chamá-lo sem precisar instanciar a classe:**

```
SuaClasse.metodo();
```

**Vantagem:** Dispensa a instanciação da classe.

**Desvantagem:** A classe corre o risco de se tornar uma classe genérica `Utilidades`, meio "perdida" no meio do código e apresentando funcionalidades esparsas e sem relação uma com a outra.

**3) Instanciar a classe e chamar o método em questão:**

```
SuaClasse objeto = new SuaClasse(contexto);
objeto.metodo();
```

**Desvantagens:** As mesmas de uma classe com métodos estáticos, com a desvantagem adicional de correr o risco de *memory leaks* por vazar um contexto que não seja o contexto global (`getApplicationContext()`). Por isso procure sempre que possível passar o contexto global no construtor da classe.

Variações possíveis dessa última forma incluem criar um **Singleton** da classe em questão ou torná-la uma subclasse de `Application`, declarando-a no `AndroidManifest.xml`. Novamente, essas formas de implementar devem ser adotadas se fizerem sentido em seu design.

Não creio que tenha citado todas as vantagens e desvantagens, melhorias são bem-vindas.

Comment: Obrigado, está muito bem explicado.